# Traversing a tree and get the depth of every object

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have a JavaScript object, let's call it 'obj'. I want to traverse this object and its descendants and find out for **each** object how many descendants it has, and hold this number on a property on the object, like `obj.numOfDescendants` or something. How can it be done recursively?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
var traversTree = function(obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
            if (!obj["numOfDescendants"])
                obj["numOfDescendants"] = 0;
            obj.numOfDescendants += traversTree(obj[k]); // Here is where I'm stuck.
                                                         // What do I return here
                                                         // in order to sum the
                                                         // depth?
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone point where I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems:

- You're expecting `traversTree` to return a value:

  ```
  obj.numOfDescendants += traversTree(obj[k]);
  ```

  ...but you're not returning a value from it in all cases, only in *some* cases. You'll want the function to always return a value.
- You're returning too early, before the loop has finished. You need to add up the result of calling `traversTree` on **all** of the object's object children.
- (Related to the previous point.) You're updating `obj.numOfDescendants` in the loop, but you don't actually know that number until the loop finishes.
- We need to count the one that we've just entered, so when adding the descendants, we need the result of calling `traversTree` on it *and* 1.

So something along the lines of:

```
var traversTree = function(obj) {
    var descendants = 0;
    for (let k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
            descendants += traversTree(obj[k]) + 1;
        }
    }
    obj.numOfDescendants = descendants;
    return descendants;
};
```

Example:

```js
var traversTree = function(obj) {
  var descendants = 0;
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
      descendants += traversTree(obj[k]) + 1;
    }
  }
  obj.numOfDescendants = descendants;
  return descendants;
};

console.log("Example 1:");
var o1 = {
  test: {}
};
traversTree(o1);
console.log(o1);

console.log("Example 2:");
var o2 = {
  a: {},
  b: {
    c: {}
  }
};
traversTree(o2);
console.log(o2);

console.log("Example 3:");
var o3 = {
  a: {},
  b: {
    c: [{}, {x:{z:"y"}}, {}]
  }
};
traversTree(o3);
console.log(o3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Side note: You've used both `var` and `let` in your code. `let` is a new keyword as of ES2015. If you're using ES2015 or above and making the switch to using `let`, it's probably best to do that consistently throughout rather than sometimes using `var`. Also look at using `const` and arrow functions where possible, for instance:

```
const traversTree = obj => {
    let descendants = 0;
    for (const k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
            descendants += traversTree(obj[k]) + 1;
        }
    }
    obj.numOfDescendants = descendants;
    return descendants;
};
```

It may look odd to see `const` for `k` above, but the mechanics of the `for` loop when you declare your iterator variable in the initializer are such that you actually end up with a new `k` for each loop iteration, and that `k`'s value never changes during the loop body, so `const` actually works there. Granted, though, it definitely looks a bit odd.

Comment: If you don't see `+ 1` on the `descendants += traversTree(obj[k]);` line above, hit refresh.

Comment: This will traverse possible arrays too? Not sure if OP needs arrays being included, though.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes, it will, because `typeof []` is `"object"` and `for-in` works on arrays (looping through the actual properties they have, ignoring any gaps in sparse arrays, which for once is what we want).

Comment: if browser doesn't support ES2015, do 'const' and 'let' have fallback?

Comment: @Joe: If your code may need to run on engines that don't support `let` and `const`, you need to *transpile* with something like http://babeljs.io and deploy the transpiled result.